# Searching for a rows that contain a value in one column in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have several columns in a spreadsheet in Excel and need to find the rows that contain the value Y in column B (CWI in example below), then print out the value of another column (e.g. Column A; Job Number in the example below) so then I can relate this to some paperwork that I need to extract data from. My spreadsheet looks like this:

```
Job Number | CWI | LI
-----------+-----+---
1114       | Y   | N
-----------+-----+---
1115       | N   | N
-----------+-----+---
1116       | Y   | Y
```

Is there some kind of script/formula I can use to iterate through all the rows and search for a value in column CWI then list the Job Number again in another column?

Comment: try http://superuser.com/questions/201434/getting-the-value-in-one-column-from-a-formula-on-another-column-in-excel http://superuser.com/questions/81498/excel-find-items-in-one-column-that-are-not-in-another-column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in D1:

```
=IF(B1="Y",A1)
```